# pathlib.Path s .unlink() not giving error

Tags: python, error-handling, pathlib

I'm trying to put code deleting files in a folder into a try/except OSError block where the except would trigger, for example, if the files or folder don't exist. However, the function doesn't error.

I stripped it down to this, without the try block:

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path("foo").glob("bar.py")

for f in p:
    f.unlink()
```

In my working directory, I have a folder `foo` with `bar.py` in it.
If I run the example code, bar.py is deleted successfully.

However, if I change p to `p = pathlib.Path("foo").glob("baz.py")`, nothing happens. I would assume this would raise an error. "Missing_ok" is set to its default, which should be False.

Why is this not throwing an error at me?

EDIT: Python 3.9.1

Thanks

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.1

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect an error? ``glob`` will only return paths of *existing files*. Providing a glob to a file that does not exist will simply match nothing, and thus delete nothing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, thank you. I'm new to programming, so I guess I don't know exactly what to expect. I have been reading this https://linuxize.com/post/python-delete-files-and-directories/#pattern-matching

I assumed the except in the last example over "pattern matching" would work for FileNotFoundErrors.

I would like to raise an error if the folder "foo" does not exist.